# Как добавить массив в скрипт в юнити?

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

Как добавить массив в скрипт в юнити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и любой массив в языке *C#*

Например массив GameObject:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {    
    public GameObject[] myArrOfGo;
}
```

Заполнить его можно либо через инспектор, либо программно в любом методе

Comment: Спасибо, немного затупил)